# Table not centering at all

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I know this question has been asked a billion times, but I've looked at the solutions and the table just refuses to center. I was hoping someone could help me.

This is what I have for the HTML:

```
<div id="paccount">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="150">Order History</td>
            <td width="28" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td width="320" rowspan="4">Personal Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="90">Preferences</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="115" colspan="3">Logout</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS for that div:

```
#paccount {
    width: 668px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

EDIT: I meant centering the text in the table, sorry.

Comment: [__Fiddle__](http://jsfiddle.net/JS9fz/)

Comment: Did you mean not centering vertically..? because you're table is taking up the full width of container so there won't be any space left to center it horizontally...

Comment: the text is already centered according to your code : http://jsfiddle.net/QLMe6/1/

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I re-opened the page and the text started centering. Not quite sure why since I haven't touched the code since a few hours ago when I was still trying to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not centering the table.

You are trying to center all the text.

You have to center that `#paccount` `div` first.

To do that:

```
#paccount{
    width:668px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin:0 auto; /* Here is the key! */
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I was trying to center the text, not the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `div` to stay centered in the page you should have:

```
#paccount {
    width: 668px;
    height: 400px;
border:1px solid black;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;  
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

but if you want the table cells to be centered you should create another css rule for the table and perhaps the cells.

Answer (score 0):

add text align to td

```
<div id="paccount">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="150">Order History</td>
            <td width="28" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td width="320" rowspan="4">Personal Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="90">Preferences</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="115" colspan="3">Logout</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
#paccount {
    width: 668px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;  
}
td{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a div named wrapper like this

HTML:

```
<div id="paccount" class="wrapper">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="150">Order History</td>
            <td width="28" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td width="320" rowspan="4">Personal Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="320" height="90">Preferences</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="115" colspan="3">Logout</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
 width: 500px; //you can change this in anything you want feel free to edit.
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: FYI: by the time you'd posted this answer, the asker updated their question to indicate they were looking to center the *text* in the cells, not the table itself.